# Changing css style triggers minor GC

Tags: jquery, css, performance, garbage-collection

I am facing memory issues in my application. In order to investigate this issue, I decided to narrow down the scope. So, I wrote following sample program where I created table of 1000*10.

```
      $('#tableDiv').innerHTML = "" ;
        var i,j;
        for (i=0; i<1000; i +=1 ) {
         for (j=0; j<10 ;j+=1 ) {
           // some html code
            }
        }

        $("#buttonClick").click(function() {
                $('.levels').css({"background-color":"red"});
            }
      });
```

On button click, I was changing background color of all the divs inside that table. When I profiled this action using chrome profiler I saw 6-7 minor GC chunks.

[image]
    So, I replaced jquery.css with native javascript implementation.

```
$("#buttonClick").click(function() {
      var objects=document.getElementsByClassName("levels");
           if(objects){
            var objLength=objects.length;
            var object;
            for(var i=0;i<objLength;i++){
                object=objects[i];
                object.style.backgroundColor="red";
            }
           }
    });
```

Minor GC reduced to two occurances. But still, they were there.

[image]

When I commented out following line, there were no GCs

```
   object.style.backgroundColor="red";
```

So, my questions are

1. Why I am seeing these two minor GCs on some style change and how to avoid those minor GCs ?
2. With jQuery.css, why more GCs are getting triggerred.

Comment: 1) because native JS is always going to be more efficient than a framework built on top of it. 2) see #1

Comment: @Rory, I understand that native JS will always be efficient than framework. But my question is why style change is triggering Minor GCs ?